# Generating class name list based on class index list

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, iris-dataset

I'm playing with `iris_dataset` from `sklearn.datasets`
I want to generate list similiar to `iris_dataset['target']` but to have name of class instead of index.
The way I did it:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
iris_dataset=load_iris()
y=iris_dataset.target
print("Iris target: \n {}".format(iris_dataset.target))
unique_y = np.unique(y)
class_seq=['']
class_seq=class_seq*y.shape[0]

for i in range(y.shape[0]):
    for (yy,tn) in zip(unique_y,iris_dataset.target_names):
        if y[i]==yy:
            class_seq[i]=tn          

print("Class sequence: \n {}".format(class_seq))
```

but I would like to do it not looping through all of the elements of `y`, how to do it better way?

The outcome is that I need this list for `pandas.radviz` plot to have a proper legend:

```
pd.plotting.radviz(iris_DataFrame,'class_seq',color=['blue','red','green'])
```

And further to have it for any other dataset.

Comment: Actually it's probably better to use mask as given in second answer cause it's easier to work with np.arrays not lists, my mistake in formulating a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo can do it by list comprehension.

```
class_seq = [ iris_dataset.target_names[i] for i in iris_dataset.target]
```

or by using map

```
class_seq = list(map(lambda x : iris_dataset.target_names[x], iris_dataset.target))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by looping over `iris_dataset.target_names.size`. This is only size 3 so it should be alot faster for large `y` arrays.

```
class_seq = np.empty(y.shape, dtype=iris_dataset.target_names.dtype)

for i in range(iris_dataset.target_names.size):
    mask = y == i
    class_seq[mask] = iris_dataset.target_names[i]
```

If you want to have `class_seq` as a list: `class_seq = list(class_seq)`